# How to fix zeros in output from RSI calculation with ta-lib in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ta-lib

I'm calculating RSI using ta-lib with Java in a spring-boot application. 
After spending some time figuring out the function call arguments, I have managed to get an output from the calculation. However, the rsi-function keeps returnings zero values in the output array. Why does it return zeros?

I'm fetching candlestick data from Binance's API, trying to calculate RSI for a given period. I have tried both the stochasticRSI and RSI, but both are returning zeros in the output array.

```
public double[] calculateRsi() {
    int OPT_IN_TIME_PERIOD = 14;

    double closePrices[] = {3553.06005859375,3572.5,3555.070068359375,3589.02001953125,3590.219970703125,3576.39990234375,3591.840087890625,3574.590087890625,3584.0,3579.56005859375,3597.6201171875,3604.949951171875,3616.2099609375,3600.8701171875,3604.010009765625,3599.010009765625,3610.679931640625,3587.909912109375,3594.8701171875,3606.1298828125,3604.39990234375,3695.3798828125,3685.739990234375,3686.530029296875,3665.300048828125,3680.719970703125,3678.8701171875,3580.0,3524.6298828125,3518.0,3539.280029296875,3530.949951171875,3526.830078125,3545.050048828125,3528.169921875,3528.820068359375,3526.89990234375,3523.0,3515.699951171875,3535.14990234375,3577.320068359375,3578.4599609375,3570.929931640625,3581.31005859375,3561.72998046875,3577.800048828125,3549.070068359375,3533.39990234375,3552.820068359375,3532.570068359375,3546.330078125,3563.22998046875,3553.409912109375,3574.929931640625,3569.6201171875,3568.06005859375,3568.47998046875,3541.969970703125,3566.919921875,3553.2099609375};

    MInteger outBegIdx = new MInteger();
    MInteger outNbElement = new MInteger();
    double[] outReal = new double[closePrices.length];
    int startIdx = 0;
    int endIdx = closePrices.length - 1;

    talibCore.rsi(startIdx, endIdx, closePrices, OPT_IN_TIME_PERIOD, outBegIdx, outNbElement, outReal);

    return outReal;
}
```

I expect the output of the calculation to be an array containing the preferred RSI values, but the actual output is the following array:

```
[
55.50236554101884,
48.4420340522227,
48.936642078369324,
39.61167139428769,
39.308159841569264,
42.58440044993444,
43.68867735156312,
50.14296711032441,
50.83654805452586,
50.79841825933019,
50.311807765799145,
45.53568823545641,
43.2867452256146,
43.38390663365912,
41.2894895311203,
41.133921783119135,
41.957983467430424,
34.6763182163226,
29.239623192248875,
43.73473552102837,
39.70980937294976,
38.722071869417974,
33.91981286332463,
40.415256033334316,
39.967050108741674,
30.237053069193013,
47.24515019760144,
48.09365697810791,
47.397062335425126,
47.919330703443016,
48.50051589076493,
45.588023453959245,
41.35162036615853,
39.976389434938056,
41.79568536987075,
36.94666938984934,
40.95986916491035,
38.21570616480444,
38.538139356924304,
39.93113081247877,
39.69620754900941,
38.9256798286741,
34.87273047865816,
43.210471567071465,
37.873988767931046,
35.92186113528669,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You shall read about function arguments one more time. You have specified period = 14 and have got N-14 results back bcs RSI is undefined for first 14 days. Bcs it requires `OPT_IN_TIME_PERIOD` close values to calculate first RSI value. Results are always stored from 0 element, so you've got 0s at end. Also after function is called the `outBegIdx` will contain index of the day which is actually corresponds to the 1st result in output. In your case should be 13 or 14, don't remember if it's 0-based. Also `outNbElement` will return actual number of meaningful values in `outReal` (N-14).

In fact there should be a `*Lookback` function for RSI and every other indicator that allows to find the size of result array for given OPT_IN_TIME_PERIOD and other OPT_ params in beforehand. So you can pass exact size to `double[] outReal = new double[M]` to use minimum memory. I guess for RSI `Lookback` function will be equal to just `closePrices.length - OPT_IN_TIME_PERIOD` but it could be more complicated for other indicators